# Table of Contents related adding items

Tags: table-of-contents

My question is if I can add certain items to the table of contents that are actually before the table of contents. So table of contents is on page 4 but preface is on page 3 is it possible to add preface to table of contents? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sure, the `toc` really doesn't care. Just remember, you need two compile runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Preface}` does exactly this. Put it behind `\section*{Preface}` or whatever you have there.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Can you please accept the answer, such that the others know that your question has been answered?

Comment: @luckyrumo: Asking for acceptance? ;-)

Comment: Had to wait 8 minutes ;)

Comment: Sorry for being impatient... It's just that gaining reputation is not that easy and I find it depressing that sometimes I can't post a useful comment due to lack of reputation. But at least I've made some progress now , thank you :-)

Comment: Gaining reputation is easy by getting upvoted and posting answers/questions too ;-) It takes a while, of course ;-)

Comment: @luckyrumo -- unless there is something else on that page, or it's preceded by `\clearpage`, putting the `\addcontentsline` *before* the `\section` could give you a page number one less than the one wanted.  better to add the line just *after* the `\section` is entered.

Comment: @barbara Thank you, I probably always had a clearpage there. I'll edit the answer